# What is the difference between the red and black box identifiers on UK airport charts?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, airport-design, airport-markings, uk, taxiways

On UK airport charts like the one below for Manchester (EGCC), what is the difference between an identifier with white lettering on a red square and one with yellow lettering on a black square with a yellow outline?

[image]
([eurocontrol.int](http://www.ead.eurocontrol.int/eadbasic/pamslight-956B9840CB2165A393EA4783410B4FB3/7FE5QZZF3FXUS/EN/Charts/AD/AIRAC/EG_AD_2_EGCC_2-1_en_2018-05-24.pdf))

Answer (score 3):

Both are hold position signs; white on red is "to protect a priority route".

> [image]
> — [UK AIP](http://www.nats-uk.ead-it.com/public/index.php.html) GEN 2.3

Below is the red J2 and black J1 as seen from the cockpit ([YouTube](https://youtu.be/17RTCTSj94I?t=341)):

> [image]
> Red J2

> [image]
> Black J1

The usage description below shows inconsistency with the map, which hints at a gradual phasing out (see 2021 update below):

> Where it is considered necessary to locate taxi-holding positions other than at runway/taxiway intersections – for example at taxiway/taxiway intersections in order to protect a priority route – the holding position should be identified by a single sign located wherever practicable on the left side of the taxiway. The sign consists of a combination of the letter designating the taxiway and a number identifying the hold position e.g. A1, A2, B2 etc. in **white on a red background.** An example of an intermediate taxi-holding position sign is shown at figure 7.13 (F).
>
> [image]
>
> — [CAP 168 Licensing of Aerodromes](https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/modalapplication.aspx?appid=11&mode=detail&id=6114)

---

### 2021 update

> [image]
> — UK AIP 20 MAY 2021

At Manchester, only yellow on black is used now. Latest AIP and CAP 168 still have the white on red option.

Comment: Thanks! I like that you referenced a YouTube too. When I first looked at this, I thought the opposite - that the yellow / black were optional, and that the write / red were mandatory (since all things regulatory in the US are in red).

Comment: @slantalpha: I've updated the answer. The red has been phased out at EGCC.